# pip3 installs a version of dependency that violates requirement specifiers

Tags: python-3.x, pip, versioning, dependency-management

I have the following two dependencies in my `requirements.txt`:

```
$ pip3 install elasticsearch==7.0.0 requests==2.21.0
Collecting elasticsearch==7.0.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a8/27/d3a9ecd9f8f972d99da98672d4766b9f62ef64c323c40bb5e2557e538ea3/elasticsearch-7.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests==2.21.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/e3/20f3d364d6c8e5d2353c72a67778eb189176f08e873c9900e10c0287b84b/requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3>=1.21.1 (from elasticsearch==7.0.0)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/ec/d93dfc69617a028915df914339ef66936ea976ef24fa62940fd86ba0326e/urllib3-1.25.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests==2.21.0)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/75/f692a584e85b7eaba0e03827b3d51f45f571c2e793dd731e598828d380aa/certifi-2019.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests==2.21.0)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5 (from requests==2.21.0)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
requests 2.21.0 has requirement urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1, but you'll have urllib3 1.25.2 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: urllib3, elasticsearch, certifi, chardet, idna, requests
Successfully installed certifi-2019.3.9 chardet-3.0.4 elasticsearch-7.0.0 idna-2.8 requests-2.21.0 urllib3-1.25.2
```

I want to understand this warning that appeared in the above output:

```
requests 2.21.0 has requirement urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1, but you'll have urllib3 1.25.2 which is incompatible.
```

Why did pip install `urllib3 1.25.2`? It does not seem to make sense. The required dependencies are:

- `elasticsearch==7.0.0` requires `urllib3>=1.21.1` ([source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/7.0.0/setup.py#L14))
- `requests==2.21.0` requires `urllib3>=1.21.1,<1.25` ([source](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v2.21.0/setup.py#L47))

Both dependencies could have been easily satisfied by installing [`urllib3 1.24.3`](https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/1.24.3/). Why did `pip3` then install `urllib3 1.25.2`? Isn't deciding the correct version according to the available requirements one of its responsibility?

It this a bug in `pip3` or is this functioning as designed?

Comment: `pip` has a rather poor dependency resolver. The feature request [#988](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988) was open in 2013 — and still is open. That's why such projects as `pipenv` and `DepHell` exist and do their own dependency resolution.

Answer (score 6):

**Update on 10th of November 2020**

Install beta version of pip, it will solve the dependencies correctly for you.

Or install latest stable and run [`pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#changes-to-the-pip-dependency-resolver-in-20-2-2020).

**Original answer**

As it is now, [pip doesn’t have true dependency resolution](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988), but instead simply uses the first specification it finds for a project.

You can add `constraints.txt` file with `urllib3==1.24.3` and then invoke:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt -c contraints.txt
```

That would do the job. When updating requirements remember to update also contraints.

Alternatively you can use one of Python [dependency managers](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/managing-dependencies/):

- [Pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/)
- [Poetry](https://poetry.eustace.io/)
- [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools)
- [DepHell](https://dephell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

See [Requirements Files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files) and [Constraints Files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#constraints-files) sections in pip user guide and [Managing Application Dependencies](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/managing-dependencies/) tutorial.